# Android toolbar tab highlighter at the top

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-tabs

I am trying to make my active tab highlighter to appear on the top of the tab element, not at the bottom, as it is at the moment when using material design theme. Is it possible to do that?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party lib -> smart tab layout: https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

Comment: thank you for your comment, but I am searching "native" solution at the moment. I hope some one did that already.

Comment: You can also check the sourcecode and do it by yourself. This lib supports more than you need. It's not that much code so it's easy understand how it works. Give it a try ;)